# Sardinas- Patterson algorithm understanding

Tags: algorithm, binary, compression

i tried to applying Sardinas- Patterson algorithm on this codewords:
C = {0,01, 0111, 01111, 11110}

but i didnt understand how,

i started with
0 is prefix of 01 -> dangling suffix is 1
List = {0,01, 0111, 01111, 11110, 1}

0 is prefix of 0111 -> dangling suffix is 111

List = {0,01, 0111, 01111, 11110, 1, 111}

0 is prefix of 01111 -> dangling suffix is 1111

List = {0,01, 0111, 01111, 11110, 1, 111, 1111}

but i do not know how to proceed...

tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of the [algorithm described by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm#Precise_description_of_the_algorithm)

First, create a function that takes two sets as input and generates a set of all the dangling suffixes:

```
SET findSuffixes( SET a, SET b )
{
    SET result = {}
    for each item x in a
        for each item y in b
        {
            if x is a prefix of y 
                result.additem( y - x )
            else if y is a prefix of x
                result.additem( x - y )
        }
    return result
}
```

And create a function that checks if any codeword appears in a given set:

```
BOOL containsCodeword( SET a, SET codewords )
```

And create a function that determines if two sets are identical:

```
BOOL setIsEqualToSet( SET a, SET b )
```

Then the algorithm looks like this

```
(A) SET codewords = { 0, 01, 0111, 01111, 11110 }
(B) SET current = findSuffixes( codewords, codewords )
(C) LIST_OF_SETS previous = {}
    forever
    {
(D)     if ( containsCodeword( current, codewords) )
           then the code is not uniquely decodable, done
        for ( each set x in previous )
(E)        if ( setIsEqualToSet( current, x )
              then the code is uniquely decodable, done

(F)     previous.additem( current )
(G)     current = findSuffixes( current, codewords )
    }
```

---

Here's a worked example:

```
(A) codewords = { 0, 01, 0111, 01111, 11110 }
(B) findSuffixes( codewords, codewords )
   0     - 0 = ignored since the result is empty
   01    - 0 = 1
   0111  - 0 = 111
   01111 - 0 = 1111
   11110 - 0 = rejected since 11110 doesn't start with 0

   0     - 01 = rejected
   01    - 01 = ignored
   0111  - 01 = 11
   01111 - 01 = 111
   11110 - 01 = rejected

   0     - 0111 = rejected
   01    - 0111 = rejected
   0111  - 0111 = ignored
   01111 - 0111 = 1 
   11110 - 0111 = rejected

   0     - 01111 = rejected
   01    - 01111 = rejected
   0111  - 01111 = rejected
   01111 - 01111 = ignored
   11110 - 01111 = rejected

   0     - 11110 = rejected
   01    - 11110 = rejected
   0111  - 11110 = rejected
   01111 - 11110 = rejected
   11110 - 11110 = ignored

    After removing duplicates, current = { 1, 11, 111, 1111 }

(D) current does not contain any of the codewords
(E) the previous list is empty, so no set in the previous list matches current
(F) at this point the set { 1, 11, 111, 1111 } is added to the previous list

(G) findsuffixes( current, codewords )
   there are 40 cases to consider
   20 cases where a member of the current set is removed from a member of codewords
   20 cases where a member of codewords is removed from a member of the current set
   most cases are rejected, the only interesting cases are

   11110 - 1    = 1110
   11110 - 11   = 110
   11110 - 111  = 10
   11110 - 1111 = 0

    So current = { 1110, 110, 10, 0 }

(D) current does contain one of the codewords, so the code in not uniquely decodable
```

Comment: how can i translate this algo to psudo code or java/c++ code?

Comment: i dont understand yet the algo
you can give me another example of codewords that is ud and not ud?
and all the way to get the answer?

Comment: @kfir91 I fixed up the example for the code set in the question. You can see that the analysis quickly becomes impossible to do by hand. A code that is uniquely decodable must generate a list of sets that have been seen before, and must continue until the `current` set is an exact duplicate of one of the sets in the list.